# Error while extracting json into case class SCALA FLINK

Tags: json, scala, serialization, apache-flink, json4s

The problem is in the map function while doing case class extraction. The case class is not serializable. I have defined formats `DefaultFormats` implicitly.

```
package org.apache.flink.quickstart
import java.util.Properties

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{JsonNode, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsStateBackend
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{DataStream, StreamExecutionEnvironment}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer09
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods
import scala.util.Try


case class CC(key:String)

object WordCount{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

    // kafka properties
    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "***.**.*.***:9093")
    properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "***.**.*.***:2181")
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "afs")
    properties.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

   val st = env
       .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09("new", new SimpleStringSchema() , properties))
       .flatMap(raw => JsonMethods.parse(raw).toOption)
//       .map(_.extract[CC])


    val l = st.map(_.extract[CC])

    st.print()
      env.execute()
  }
}
```

The error :

> INFO [main] (TypeExtractor.java:1804) - No fields detected for class
>   org.json4s.JsonAST$JValue. Cannot be used as a PojoType. Will be
>   handled as GenericType
>       Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: Task not
>   serializable
>         at org.apache.flink.api.scala.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:172)
>         at org.apache.flink.api.scala.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
>         at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment.scalaClean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.scala:666)
>         at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream.clean(DataStream.scala:994)
>         at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream.map(DataStream.scala:519)
>         at org.apache.flink.quickstart.WordCount$.main(WordCount.scala:38)
>         at org.apache.flink.quickstart.WordCount.main(WordCount.scala)
>       Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json4s.DefaultFormats$$anon$4
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
>         at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:317)
>         at org.apache.flink.api.scala.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:170)
>         ... 6 more
>
> ```
> Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to to put

```
implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
```

outside the main function like

```
object WordCount{

    implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
    def main(args: Array[String])
```

OR lazily initialize formats like

```
implicit lazy val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
```

inside the main function like

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    implicit lazy val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
```

Comment: What a simple but counterintuitive solution... Was stuck trying to debug this for an hour..